# i want to add fade in effect in product li one by one after some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

**i want all products list fade one by one after some delay according to my page height**

- i don't want all li comes in one time for full page
- i want when i scroll 300px  then 3  li shows according to my page height
- i don't won't to define scroll height ,i want it will take height according to my product li height
- when i  scroll more again 3 more li shows i hope someone understand

**below code load all li after some delay bt in one time for full page**

**i want all products li load according to how much i scroll,it means products li depend on page height**

```
<div  id="category-products" class="negi_fade">
<ul>
   <li>karbon</li>
   <li>karbon</li>
   <li>karbon</li>

if (scroll >= 600) {

  // $j(".negi_fade").fadeIn(2000);
  $j('.negi_fade li').each(function(index) {
        $j(this).delay(250*index).fadeIn(400);
  });
```

Comment: Just asking, is it possible to use jQuery or do you want a javascript only solution?

Comment: @Canvas I think the OP is using jQuery, see **$j**

Comment: @IrvinDominin oohh yea indeed sorry about that. I have edited the question to include jQuery tag

Comment: pls any suggestion???

Comment: That is called **infinite list**, and you should simply use an existing plugin for it... [there are several](http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/) for jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul negi

your code is working properly but you need make little change.

apply below CSS code and Jquery Code

```
  <style>
#category-products>ul>li
{
display:none;
}
</style>


//Jquery Code
if($(document).scrollTop()>=600)
{
$('.negi_fade li').each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(250*index).fadeIn(400);
  });
}
```